# Can't get static IPs configured correctly

Tags: linux, networking, ip, static-ip

Normally, I would just keep trying to figure this out on my own, but I'm really at my wits' end. I have a server with two Ethernet adapters, `eth0` and `eth1`. I've been assigned a `/29` subnet that technically ranges from `xxx.xxx.xxx.248` to `xxx.xxx.xxx.255`, but the only usable address are from `.250` to `.254`. For some reason `.248` is reserved, and `.249` is the default gateway.

At first, I tried `ip addr add xxx.xxx.xxx.248/29 dev eth0 broadcast +` and `ip addr add xxx.xxx.xxx.248/29 dev eth1 broadcast +`, hoping that Linux would be intelligent and assign itself different address in the block. However, both of the addresses it chose were the restricted `.248` address, so that's obviously not right.

Then I did `ip addr add xxx.xxx.xxx.250/29 dev eth0 broadcast +` and `ip addr add xxx.xxx.xxx.251/29 dev eth1 broadcast +`, which seemed to work, so I followed it with `ip route add default via xxx.xxx.xxx.249`. However, pinging `.249` resulted in "Destination Host Unreachable" so I've clearly done something wrong. I also attempted the same thing using `ifconfig` and `route`, but got the same results, so there's clearly something I'm not understanding.

What do I need to do?

Comment: xxx.xxx.xxx.248 is reserved in a /29 subnet for the same reason xxx.xxx.xxx.0 is reserved in a /24 (Class C) subnet -- it has a host number of 0 (or “all 0s”, looking at it bitwise) and so it is the address of the network as a whole, and so cannot be used for a host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CRUX documentation has some [configuration examples](http://crux.nu/Main/Handbook2-7#ntoc55).

EDIT: Set the broadcast explicitly in the `ip` command:

```
ip addr add xxx.xxx.xxx.250/29 dev eth0 broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.255
```

According to the `ip` documentation, it does try to guess but it's probably best to eliminate moving parts.

Then bring up the adapter with:

```
ip link set eth0 up
```

Try doing a tcpdump (if you can) of traffic going out to your gateway:

tcpdump host xxx.xxx.xxx.249

Comment: I've been making pretty extensive use of those, actually. Unfortunately, doing that for both `eth0` and `eth1` didn't fix anything.

Comment: Try the same command, but specify the netmask? I can't think of anything else except that it wants to use classful network masks for some utterly broken reason.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add the netmask to `ip link` and the help doesn't have anything. Would you mind posting the command?

Comment: Set the broadcast equal to the netmask? Did you really mean that?

Comment: Oops! Fixing the answer

Comment: It's working! Specifying the broadcast address did it. I feel so stupid, I could have sworn I had tried that already. Maybe that was one of the times when I used `.248` instead of `.250`. Thank you SO much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome amigo! Glad you got it working

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in the `ip addr` command.

The issue is that you are applying an IP that belongs to the same subnet on different interfaces.
Check the following:

1. Cables should be connected on the same subnet (both of them, because this is what it seems you want to do).
2. Check routing tables `netstat -rn`. Identify which interface it is using to communicate with it.

Your ping cannot properly ARP the MAC and cannot determine the interface to use to ping the gateway, probably because of a routing issue or the cable is disconnected.

If cables are properly connected, delete the auto generated route for that subnet.